# Finding probability $P({X}^{2}<0)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis, probability-distributions, density-function

Probability density function of random variable $X$ is ${f}_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{2\theta}$ where $-\theta <x<\theta $ . Calculate probability $P({X}^{2}<0)$.

I'm little bit confused. I thought that ${X}^{2}$ is never less than $0$ so $P(\oslash )=0$, is it true? Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, $P[X^2<0]=P(\emptyset)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

> I solve the first part but the second part, I'm little bit confused

You are perfectly right.

as $X^2\geq 0$, $\forall X$ the requested probability is zero

---

Perhaps there is a typo....you can calculate $P(X^2<\theta)=\theta^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

(this makes sense and the question looks similar to the one you posted)

Comment: thanks for help